# The queue resource do not release after some big sql executed in trino

Tags: trino

I use resource-groups to limit the different users resource to access the trino cluster.

But sometimes, after some big sql executed,the queue resource do not release.

After that I need to restart the cluster to recover it that is effect the other users.

Is there any way to release the queue resource without restart the trino cluster?